# Clean input value in react

Tags: reactjs

I use useState hook:

```
const [newGlass, setNewGlass] = useState({});
```

Then I make "input" as controlled in my component:

```
<input ref={nameRef} value={newGlass.name} onChange={handleNameChange} type="text" className="form-control" name="name" id="name" />
```

My "handleNameChange" function:

```
function handleNameChange(e) {
    newGlass.name = e.target.value;
    setNewGlass(newGlass);
}
```

My submit function:

```
function submit() {
    console.log("submited", newGlass, nameRef, whyRef);
    newGlass.id = i++;
    let newState = [Object.assign({}, newGlass), ...glassWords];
    setNewGlass({});
    nameRef.current.value = "";

    setGlassWords(newState);
}
```

The question is why if I try to make input empty after Submit it don't work?

Only refs helps me. If I try just to set "setNewGlass({});" values in my form inputs stay the same as before Submit.

If I try to "setNewGlass({name: ""});" - then after it I couldn't change input value at all.

What I do wrong? How to make correct controlled input without refs?

May be I should not use object for useState? But in docs I saw that this hook works fine with objects.

P.S. I try to make "handleNameChange" immutable but it has no effect.

UPD. Oh I forgot to tell that if I use separate "const [newGlassName, setNewGlassName] = useState("");" it all works fine and my input become empty after "setNewGlassName("");".

But I have about 13 input fields in my form and I try to understand how to use Object in useState hook.

UPD2. I try to add "console.log(newGlass);" to my component and remove refs. Now when I make Submit my component function starts and "console.log(newGlass);" say "{}". This means that my inputs had to become empty, but they are not!

This leads to thought that React may be compare states by references and do not start re-render of my component? I'm confused...

Can anybody please help me what can I try to do to force React re-render? Or it will be better if I will help React to understand when he need to make re-render? Or it will be better to use class instead of function component?

I guess I need something like "shouldComponentUpdate()" but for functional component, not class you know?

Comment: function handleNameChange(e) {
    setNewGlass({name: e.target.value});
}

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to change the `handleNameChange` function. and it could be something like this:

```js
function handleNameChange(e) {
    setNewGlass(e.target.value);
}
```

then you have to change the `onSubmit` function.

```js
function submit(e) {
    //dont forget to use e.preventDefault()
    e.preventDefault();
    let currentName = newGlass;
    currentName.id = 2;
    setGlassWord(currentName)
    setNewGlass({})
}
```

I think it should work, by the way you didn't ask a detailed question and if you want to get better answers you should consider adding more code to your question.

Comment: "setNewGlass(e.target.value);" - but I try to use object value for it "const [newGlass, setNewGlass] = useState({});"

The idea is quiet simple. I want to use one object for one form and I want to have an opportunity for changing and sending as one-piece object.

For example we have Human object that have such fields as: First Name, Last Name, Phone, Email, Address. And I want to add all this fields to one object like "{lastName: 'my last name', email: 'current email'}", but not separatly as you recommend "setNewGlass(e.target.value);".

Answer (score -2):

I am not familiar with the useState hook, here is what I would do:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {name: ""}
    this.handleNameChange = this.handleNameChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleNameChange() {
    // call your setGlassWords if you need
    this.setState({name: e.currentTarget.value})
  } 

  render() {
    return (
      <input value={this.state.name} onChange={handleNameChange} type="text" className="form-control" name="name" id="name" />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: you're not setting state correctly! and OP asked for hooks

Comment: Oh, sorry. No need for the exclamation mark though, just trying to help here. A good answer could also have been: RTFM, since controlled inputs are discussed in the documentation.